# Store user settings for Google Assistant via Dialogflow and C# Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I would like to get some starting tips:

I have a Google Assistant Action that communicates with an existing Rest-API (via an Http triggered Azure Function).

This API uses a 6 digit code to call the Authenticate Service, which returns a Long lived Token (never expires) and all the actual calls to the Rest API will need that token.

This 6 digit code comes from a portal. This portal can be accessed with a login. So this is a user-only code and thus the generated token will be user specific.

Now, how can I provide this authentication-service within my Google Assistant/Dialogflow??

I have no idea how to do this with Google Assistant/DialogFlow/C# azure functions or even where to start.

(I have a working Action, but it only works with my own token hard-coded)

I'm aware of the fact that there might be some legal/privacy issues when storing the Code or Token. The portal also mentions something about OAuth2 authentication but doesn't go any deeper with that.

This is more of a Proof of Concepts thing for me.

Comment: Can you [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57964759/edit) to clarify a few things: Where does the 6 digit code come from? Is it tied to a user? How would a new user get their 6 digit code? Does this mean the Token is also tied to a user and, if so, are you allowed to store this Token in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Your first requirement is to uniquely identify the user. This isn't trivial, as DialogFlow only stores unique sessions, not users. For Google Actions, you can use the approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59199489/12473533).

Once you know the user you can use the [user storage](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/save-data#saving_data_across_conversations) to save the auth-code locally. Note that this can be cleared or disabled by the user. If you need something more reliable/persistent/controllable then you could store the information in an [Azure Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-overview), which integrates well with Azure Functions via [bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table) or the [client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet). Naturally, this is only a suggestion - you could store the same association in any other database.

Comment: Thanks. 

The part "OriginalDetectIntentRequest.Payload.Fields.ContainsKey("user")"  never has any fields. With testing from Dialogflow or testing with Google Assistant Test. My account is linked to Google (Sign In required = true)

Comment: Without having done further testing, this sounds like you didn't [configure the action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in#configure_the_project). Also, the DialogFlow test console never sends this payload, so you must use the Google Actions Simulator or a real device for testing.

Comment: I configured the action as instructed and tested through the Google Assistant Simulator, still the same issue...

Comment: Alright. When you access the intent with a real device, are you asked by the Assistant to link your account? If not, the action is not configured properly. Otherwise, check if the JSON you receive (not the object parsed from it) contains the payload/user part.